# Cannot get tail command with output redirection working

Tags: bash, shell, grep, tail, buffering

This works:

```
tail -f debug.log | grep RFC
```

...but this does not:

```
tail -f debug.log | grep RFC > file.log
```

Can you help me figure out why?

Answer (score 1):

### Your problem

Your output is buffered and redirected to `file.log` only when `tail` and `grep` are done. That's because, by default, `grep` keeps its output buffered when it does not output to a terminal (in your case, the output goes the file `file.log`).

`tail` used with its `-f` option never stops sending output to `grep`, which never sent its output in the redirection since `grep` waits for `tail` to stop sending input before writing its buffer to your output file.

### Solution

To redirect your command's output to a file, you can use `grep`'s `--line-buffered` option:

```
tail -f debug.log | grep --line-buffered RFC > file.log
```

### Source

From `grep`'s man page:

> ```
>  --line-buffered
>          Force output to be line buffered.  By default, output is line
>          buffered when standard output is a terminal and block buffered
>          otherwise.
> ```